# defining a plane in R3 with just three numbers

Tags: data-structures, geometry, plane

all the plane definitions i've found use either four numbers (for the plane normal and distance from origin definition) or six numbers (for the plane normal and point that is on the plane definition).

maybe i'm missing something, but shouldn't it be possible to define a plane with only three numbers, (nx, ny, nz) using the direction of the vector as the plane normal and the magnitude of the vector as the distance from the origin?

i am trying to write a game that generates billions of planes, and shaving 25% off of my plane struct would really help.

Comment: When the plane is through the origin, the vector has no direction information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, at the cost of recalculating the distance to the origin every time you need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a solution using 3 parameters that has no degenerate case, use two direction angles `(U, V)` and the distance to the origin `D`.

Equation of the plane: `cos(U).X + sin(U).cos(V).Y + sin(U).sin(V).Z = D`.

If high accuracy is not mandated, you can store the angles as shorts, with suitable scaling, achieving 0°00'20" resolution. With float `D`, this packs to 8 bytes per plane.